# WPF Telerik RadGridView Disappeared when Global Style Applied

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

WPF Telerik RadGridView disappeared when i applied global style.

**GridViewStyle.xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:fw="clr-namespace:SSMS.Framework;assembly=SSMS.Framework">

    <Style TargetType="telerik:RadGridView">
        <Setter Property="ShowGroupPanel" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="RowIndicatorVisibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserFreezeColumns" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="BoldStyle" TargetType="telerik:GridViewRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource GridViewRowStyle}">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    </Style>

...........................etc
```

If i remove the below part from GridViewStyle.xaml, the grid appearing fine, but i want to configure those settings globally.

> ```
> <Style TargetType="telerik:RadGridView">
>             <Setter Property="ShowGroupPanel" Value="False" />
>             <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
>             <Setter Property="RowIndicatorVisibility" Value="Collapsed" />
>             <Setter Property="CanUserFreezeColumns" Value="False" />
>             <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
>             <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
>         </Style>
> ```

I am using Telerik WPF 2016.1.112.45

I am sure, before it was worked on the version 2015.3.1104.45.

Anyone faced this issue?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution Found!**

I removed the reference from **Binaries.NoXaml** folder

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\UI for WPF Q1
>   2016\Binaries.NoXaml\WPF45\Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.dll

and added the reference from **Binaries** folder.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\UI for WPF Q1
>   2016\Binaries\WPF45\Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.dll

Now everything working fine:)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful! Do not mix dll!!!

if you are using implicit styles, you must always use **BasedOn**:

```
<Style TargetType="telerik:RadGridView" BasedOn="{StaticResource GridViewRowStyle}">
        <Setter Property="ShowGroupPanel" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="RowIndicatorVisibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserFreezeColumns" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
    </Style>
```

Comment: Yes you're right. But "BasedOn" not working for TargetType="telerik:RadGridView". So I just removed implicit styles dlls.